# Losing Excel clipboard data after protecting sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to run VBA to Hide & Unhide Excel columns **without** running the Unprotect sheet function in VBA (given that the worksheet is protected by default)?

When protecting a sheet and allowing for "Format columns", I can freely Hide and Unhide whatever column I wish, even though the sheet is protected. For some reason VBA neglects that and although Excel seems to allow Hide/Unhide function, macro will report an error and ask the sheet protection to be removed.

This would not even be a problem without another peculiar functionality as when there is something copied from Excel to a clipboard and the macro ends with Protect sheet function, copied data is eventually lost. Again - not something that happens when done manually nor would look sensible.

Any ideas? I guess either of those things would solve my main issue.

Edit: sorry, forgot to post the VBA code. It was getting very late:

```
Sub Copy()
'
' Copy Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$I$290").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="<>"
    Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("H:H").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Application.Goto Reference:="Range"
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("H:H").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
    , AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, _
    AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
    ActiveWindow.LargeScroll Down:=-2
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have no problems doing it. Make sure you use the `.columns` attribute like `range("M:N").columns.Hidden=true`

Comment: Any chance we can see your code?  It will help us help you.

Comment: Sorry, added the code, it was getting late...

Answer (score 1):

[Protect the worksheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx) with the UserInterfaceOnly:=True parameter and you can do anything you want in VBA while restricting the user normally.

```
sub protectOnce()
    worksheets("sheet1").unprotect password:="123"
    worksheets("sheet1").protect password:="123", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
end sub
```

Comment: I would presume that this code expects VBA to first protect the worksheet? I have a worksheet that I have manually protected and saved first which is used as a template and then the user can operate macros out of which one is a copy function. So as of now - before the user launches any macros, the template would already be saved as a protected sheet.