# Excel VBA - random runtime errors

Tags: excel, vba

I’m very new to Excel VBA but managed to create three buttons in a staff timesheet.  All buttons work as needed, however, one particular button is causing random issues – about 90% of the time it works, but from time to time it will crash Excel or give an error such as runtime error '-2147417848 (800 10 108)': Automation error    The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.  Other times it’s a similar message, saying Method ‘Insert’ of object ‘Range’ failed.
It’s happening in different versions of Excel on different computers.  The task is not complex but I’m stumbling with my VBA knowledge.
The user clicks the button to set up each formatted row in the sheet called “Timesheet”, i.e. clicking the button in “Timesheet” copies a row from sheet4 (formatted and containing formulae) and inserts it into the “Timesheet” above the button.
I’d be very grateful if someone could suggest alternative code that won’t crash Excel - many thanks in advance!

```
Sub NewSlot()

' NewSlot Macro used in Timesheet
'
    'turn protection off
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Unprotect Password:="mypasswd"
    Worksheets("Timesheet").Unprotect Password:=" mypasswd "

    ' select row 8 in sheet4
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Rows("8").Select
    Selection.Copy

    ' go back to timesheet
    Sheets("Timesheet").Select

    ' insert copied row
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
    Range(Cells(r.Row, r.Column), Cells(r.Row, r.Column)).Offset(0, 0).Select

    Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False


    'turn protection on
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Protect Password:=" mypasswd "
    Worksheets("Timesheet").Protect Password:=" mypasswd"

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are going to use VBA to modify a protected worksheet, unprotect it then protect it once with UserInterfaceOnly:=True (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49990911/losing-excel-clipboard-data-after-protecting-sheet/49991531#49991531)). After that has been done once you will not have to unprotect to modify with VBA. If you have to unprotect it for another reason, reprotect it with with UserInterfaceOnly:=True.

Comment: It seems like you have the same teacher as T Wilken [Dynamic button - Runtime error 1004 - Unable to get the Buttons property of the Worksheet class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51164543/9912714).  Your Timesheet password doesn't match.  Consider passing the target range as a parameter.  This can be a difficult error to get around.  Follow @Jeeped 's advice.

Comment: Watch: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&t=3123s&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use VBA to repeatedly modify a protected worksheet, unprotect it then protect it once with UserInterfaceOnly:=True.

```
sub protectOnce()
    worksheets("Timesheet").unprotect password:="mypasswd"
    worksheets("sheet4").unprotect password:="mypasswd"
    worksheets("Timesheet").protect password:="mypasswd", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    worksheets("sheet4").protect password:="mypasswd", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
end sub
```

After that has been done once you will not have to unprotect to modify with VBA. If you have to unprotect it for another reason, reprotect it with with UserInterfaceOnly:=True.

This cuts your NewSlot code down significantly. It is considered 'best practise' to avoid using Select and Activate, particularly across worksheets.

```
Sub NewSlot()

    ' select row 8 in sheet4
    workSheets("Sheet4").Rows("8").Copy

    ' go back to timesheet
    with workSheets("Timesheet")
        ' insert copied row
        Dim r As Range
        Set r = .Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
        .Cells(r.Row, "A").entirerow.Insert shift:=xlDown
    end with

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much, appreciate it!